# CodeIgniter Hooks Pre Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use different databases for different language files. I can get language code with this;

```
$this->lang->lang()
```

I have to define it as pre_controller hook, so system will select right database at the beginning. But when I try to use the code above, I'm getting a fatal error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Hooks::$lang
>
> Filename: config/hooks.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function lang() on a non-object in...

This is my code;

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = define('LANG', isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : $this->lang->lang());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this.     $this->CI->lang->lang()

Comment: Same. 

 Call to a member function lang() on a non-object

Comment: Try this. It should be work. $CI =& get_instance(); $CI->lang->lang();

Comment: I got different error now; Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\firmav1\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233